# Javascript - Download multiple links in one click

Tags: javascript, download

The title might not be explicit enough, so let me explain my problem:
I have a list of links displayed on my page, pointing to audio files. Clicking each one of those will prompt the browser to download the targeted file.

What I would like to have is a `<button>` at the bottom that would download every link of the list.

Here is my code:

```js
const downloadAll = () => {
  const allLinks = document.querySelectorAll('a');

  for (i=0; i< allLinks.length; i++) {
    allLinks[i].click();
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="https://link1">Download</a>
<a href="https://link2">Download</a>
<a href="https://link3">Download</a>

<button onclick="downloadAll()">download all</button>
```

When the user clicks on `<button>` only **the last one** is downloaded.

I have searched a lot and tried different options but I couldn't find a working one. I think the `download` part is the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use download attribute to assign filename to each `a` tag
that will trigger mulltiple download in browser

```js
const downloadAll = () => {
  const allLinks = document.querySelectorAll('a');

  for (i=0; i<= allLinks.length; i++) {
    var each = allLinks[i]
    each.download = each.href
    each.click()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try adding target="_blank" to your links like so

```
<a href="https://link1" target="_blank">Download</a>
<a href="https://link2" target="_blank">Download</a>
<a href="https://link3" target="_blank">Download</a>
```

this will tell browser to process every link in a separate tab. Tabs might be blocked by the browser though, so pay attention to top right corner(in chrome) there may be notification regarding blocked popups.

Here is the link to an article that shows some other ways using different libs.
https://medium.com/twodigits/multi-file-download-using-javascript-9b0b8a14639b

Comment: Thank you so much this actually worked!!! I have been on it for several hours...
Chrome initially blocked the pop-ups but I had the option to authorise them. So, I have a follow-up question if that is OK: as a user experience, would that be OK to offer this solution?

Comment: You're most  welcomeI just edited the answer added a link to a small article that uses various popular libs to do this, just in case :)

Comment: To be honest I'd always try to find a way that would simplify user experience, I mean the less actions users would do the better. Try some of the JS download libs like FileSaver, StreamSaver. I don't remember if you can download multiple files with one popup or no though. Worth trying.

Comment: Absolutely. The problem I am facing is that the files are hosted on a completely different server as the app. I have made something similar to what you are suggesting work, but with files stored in a folder in my app, but not "remotely" stored files. I am sure there is a way around, maybe with s3 storage, I just have to figure it out.
In any case, this is perfect as a temporary solution, and I am very grateful for your help:)